# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()

Tags: php, wordpress, function, header, undefined

I am using this code to go to a page.  In my directory 
there is theme folder ch.

```
<li>
<a href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/ch/bn1.php">
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/bn1.png">
</a>
</li>
```

But going to page url wp-content/themes/live/ch/bn1.php shows this message

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\wamp\www\blog\wp-content\themes\live stream\ch\bn1.php on line 1

My theme directory is

```
www/blog/wp-content/themes/live stream
```

My page to go to the directory is

```
www/blog/wp-content/themes/live stream/ch/bn1.php
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post.  I have also marked your urls.  Note that I marked the error message with a leading >.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling that file, but you are not loading up the rest of WordPress. Therefore `get_header()` doesn't exist.

WordPress does not work the way you are trying to use it here. You should create a page template, then create a page in the WordPress admin with this template and then link to the page URL which will be shown in the page editing screen. You can't just link straight to the template.

To create page templates the WordPress way try reading https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/