# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header() , line 1

Tags: php, wordpress, file, xampp, wordpress-theming

I am new in PHP. I added file to themes and activated it but when I run index.php it shows the following error. and also I have this problem with every functions in index.php

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sajadwp\wp-content\themes\newtheme\index.php:1 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sajadwp\wp-content\themes\newtheme\index.php on line 1

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do any of these help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47882680/4705262 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34576777/4705262